# What's the difference between "truculent" and "aggressive"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

If you don't mind, please compare them also to "belligerent" and "bellicose".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truculent has overtones of defiance; aggressive means attacking, or threatening to attack, others.

Belligerent and bellicose are near synonyms, and are fairly closely related to aggressive.  Both imply warlike attitudes - attacking, or threatening to attack.